I cannot get the scanf function to work while using VScode
I made a simple program for a class using c and printf would work just fine; however, when I added the Scanf function, nothing would work not even the printf lines. My teacher used the same code on VS and it worked but nothing for me.
I made sure I had C extensions downloaded and all looked fine it just seems Scanf isn't working. Here is the code in question:
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int num =0;
    printf("%s", "Enter Your number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    printf("number is %d\n", num);

}

So I see your responses and it works in the terminal but not in VS Code so I added this as well:
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    char buf[128] = ""; 
    int num =0;
    printf("%s", "Enter Your number: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    sscanf("buf", "%d", &num);
    printf("number is %d\n", num);

return 0;
}   

It now prints "Enter Your Number: Number is 0" and doesn't give me the chance to change that as a "user"

Just one word of advice: Never use the result of a scanf without checking that the scan actually succeeded.

Also pay heed to man 3 scanf "It is very difficult to use these functions correctly, and it is preferable to read entire lines with fgets(3) or getline(3) and parse them later with sscanf(3) or more specialized functions such as strtol(3)." Hint: char buf[128] = ""; fputs ("Enter your number: ", stdout); followed by if (fgets (buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL || sscanf (buf, "%d", &num) != 1) { fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid integer '%s'.\n", buf);  return 1; }  Protects against virtually all user-mischief.

@CodyT After int num =0; ... sscanf("buf", "%d", &num); runs, what value do you expect to see in num?  (Hint, user input is not asked for here.)

https://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html is informative reading.

@chux-ReinstateMonica So what I would like to have happen is it prints "Enter your number" then you can enter a number and then it prints "Here is your number: user entered number." If that is not what scanf is doing how would I get user input?

@Shawn I read that, copied the code into my VS Code, ran the code and there was no output. This was the code i copyed from the site:#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
int a;
char buf[1024]; // use 1KiB just to be sure
do
{
printf("enter a number: ");
if (!fgets(buf, 1024, stdin))
{
// reading input failed, give up:
return 1;
}
// have some input, convert it to integer:
a = atoi(buf);
} while (a == 0); // repeat until we got a valid number
printf("You entered %d.\n", a);
}

@CodyT Perhaps by now you see that "If that is not what scanf is doing how would I get user input?" will not scan from stdin using sscanf("buf", "%d", &num); as that is sscanf(), which reads from a string, and not scanf(), with reads from stdin..

Problem 1
You stated:

nothing would work not even the printf lines

Are you referencing, that there is no output at all? Does the program return? Do you see next shell prompt?
Looks like you are experiencing what is called buffering.
Try following:
Insert fflush(stdout); before scanf line. You will see the result of first printf.
Problem 2
Maybe after the part 1 fix you will see the prompt, but you will be unable to enter anything. In that case there may be the issue with the IDE you are using. That IDE may have the "plumbing" done wrong.
Each app uses 3 pipes: stdin, stdout and stderr.
stdin is used as an input for scanf and some other functions, while stdout is used by printf.
Your app reads the stdin, processes it and outputs something to stdout.
If your IDE is connecting some dead pipe to stdin, instead of real terminal's "keyboard input" pipe, than you have to reconfigure it.
Here is the simple bash example of piping:
$ echo "317" | ./a.out
Enter Your number: number is 317

I have compiled your program and called is the unusual way.

I first called echo, which is just printing something to it's own stdout.
I called your app
I connected both those apps using pipe (|) symbol, so stdout of first app is fed out to second app's stdin.

You can make it even more advanced - you can pipe multiple apps to a come form of conveyor - output of one app is fed to another app. Here is the example, that seem to obvious:
$ echo "317" | ./a.out | hexdump -C
00000000  45 6e 74 65 72 20 59 6f  75 72 20 6e 75 6d 62 65  |Enter Your numbe|
00000010  72 3a 20 6e 75 6d 62 65  72 20 69 73 20 33 31 37  |r: number is 317|
00000020  0a                                                |.|
00000021

Long story short - try to run the app from raw terminal and check, that it works. If that is the case, go trough all your VS Code settings and find parameter, that selects source for stdin.

You can get a proper terminal using Windows Explorer: navigate to the location of the exe, then click on the URI / Location bar — it’ll change to a text input box. Type “cmd” and press Enter. Now you have a terminal. Type the name of your program’s exe and press Enter.

Things work similarly on Linux. For example, using Gnome, you can right-click in Nemo and select “Open in terminal”.

Hello, so I tried in the terminal and it worked just fine but in VS Code it doesn't. I also put in the Flush the first guy was talking about and that made the first one show up however I don't see anything for stdin in settings... I have the first 3 Microsoft C/C++ extensions installed and nothing sticks out with them.

Cody T, how do you start your application from VS Code? Is there any parameters at all? I'm not using it, but in all cases there should be some way to configure execution environment, including stdin source. In case nobody will be able to help with VS Code, we can try to troubleshoot it in zoom or google meet

@nv317 I just run the code which is what my teacher would do in VS and it would work and I copied exactly what some other people with vs code would do and it didnt seem to work...
